# get an entity using Doctrine 2 ans Synfony 2

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have three objects :

Categorie ,Article and Image.

Categories and Article have bidirectional OneToMany association. 
Article and Image have bidirectional OneToMany association.

How can I get a certain category with all its Articles and for each article all its image ?

in the end I would like to get:

`categorie.articles[0].images[0].URL` (twig syntax)

PS: URL is a parameter of Image.

I succeded to get the assiciated Articles to a certain Category with creating a custom Repository Function:

```
public function getCategoryWithArticles($article)
{
    $qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->select('a')
    ->from('SiteBundle:Category', 'a')
    ->where('a.article= :article')
    ->setParameter('article', $article);

    $qb->leftJoin('a.articles', 'c')
    ->addSelect('c');
    return $qb->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
}

What should I add to get also the Images associated to each article ?
```

Answer (score 1):

So you have article objects associated to a certain category. Just use something like

```
$article->getImages();
```

to get all the images for an article.